# Calling a function on form load

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I have a program that contains a function that grabs information from text file a populates labels. How can I have this function called on loading of the form? I tried calling it like this:

```
class app:
    def __init__(self,master):
        #Code to pack frame and load objects
        app.updateSIP() #Function I am trying to call
    def updateSIP(self):
        #Code that pulls data from text file
root = Tk()
root.wm_title('title')
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I know the function works because when its called from another function it works. The error I get is:

```
NameError: global name 'app' is not defined
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. You named your class `app` but here:

   ```
   app = App(root)
   ```

   you try to use it as `App`.  Python is case-sensitive, so this action will raise a  `NameError`.
2. `updateSIP` requires an instance of `App` as its first argument.  However, you invoke it like this:

   ```
   app.updateSIP()
   ```

   The above  will raise a `TypeError` because it doesn't give `updateSIP` an instance of `App`.

   Instead, it should be written like this:

   ```
   self.updateSIP()
   ```

---

All in all, your code should be written like this:

```
class App:
    def __init__(self,master):
        #Code to pack frame and load objects
        self.updateSIP() #Function I am trying to call
    def updateSIP(self):
        #Code that pulls data from text file
root = Tk()
root.wm_title('title')
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks! the app/App was a typo on my part when entering the code into the web form. Calling it with self did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

The name of your class is `app()`, but you are calling an instance of the class with `App()`. Python is case sensitive, just change:

```
app = App(root)
```

to:

```
app = app(root)
```

Or, to stick with PEP8 standards, rename your `app()` class to `App()` :)